# Can anyone explain to me what this Script does?

Tags: matlab, math, octave

This code it's an Integration method used to accept as input parameters the values from  integration nodes.(Excuse my bad english)

This is part of least approach method.

```
function s = simpson(x,y)
    n = length(x);
    h = x(2)-x(1);
    s = h/3*(y(1)+y(n)+4*sum(y(2:2n-1))+2*sum(y(3:2:n-2)));
```

I'm trying to run the code on octave online and opens a windows to insert the value of X and Y but... this is what gives to me...

```
error: invalid use of script /home/oo/Simpson.m in index expression
```

I don't know what to do, please I really needsome help!

Explain to me like you were talking to a little kid... (This is because of my lack of english skillss)

Thanks From the buttom of my hearth :3

Comment: My teacher told me to name the Script like Simpson.m

Comment: you may be interested in reading about [Simpson's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule)

Comment: why didnt you ask your teacher what it did when they gave it to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is almost OK but in last line by refer to [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule) there was a little error so change this line as follow

```
s = h/3*(y(1)+y(n)+4*sum(y(2:2:n-1))+2*sum(y(3:2:n-2)));
```

and for test your function suppose we have two vector `x=[1 2 3]` and `y=[2 3 4]` then we type below code in command windoe

```
x = [1 2 3];
y = [2 3 4];
simpson(x,y)

ans=
   6
```

Comment: -.-' yeah that was it... Now shows a different error: simpson: A(I): index out of bounds; value 2 out of bound 1
error: called from simpson at line 3 column 7 --------> this line h = x(2)-x(1);

Comment: Please add this error to your question(by edit) then i can edit my answer

Comment: how you enter function inputs?

Comment: i think you get scalar value to your function

Comment: i edit my answer so if this answer is ok please apply that

Comment: Could it be the values that im giving to x and y?  x = 0.5 and y = 0.3

Comment: yeah that's wrong , integral have to be in interval and can't be on point